# Why I did what I did

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

> Why I did, what I did

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

And can it be used in a situation where If a task can be done in multiple ways and someone has to explain "Why they did, what they did"

(While writing this, I've got a feeling that it seems wrong but this sounds interesting way to explain, if it is grammatically correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why I did what I did** is not a sentence. It is just a clause.

It cannot stand meaningfully by itself.

To turn it into a sentence you have to add something to it, such as:

> This is why I did what I did.

or

> She asked me why I did what I did.

Comment: "Why, I did what I did!" is a perfectly acceptable sentence. So, it's not just changing the words that can make it meaningful, it's also, as in this case, changing how the same words are presented.

Comment: @JasonBassford +1 I hate how that works. Since it makes it so hard to actually decide if a written sentence without context (and possibly imperfect punctuation) is grammatical.

Comment: @DRF A written (or spoken) sentence without context is not English: it is merely a conundrum.